# Access data from weather API using Vue.js, chart.js and chartjs-plugin-datalabels

Tags: api, vue.js, chart.js

This post [Add direction arrow as point style in line chart and have user supply direction/angle/rotation in data series](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/5667) helped me some of the way. But I can't figure out how to access the wind direction data in my exempel (from row 200 and down)
I tried
`data: [{s: this.windspeeds, a: this.winddeg}]`
and
`ctx.dataset.data[ctx.dataIndex].a`

In the JSFiddle examples [simonbrunel](/simonbrunel) used the same data in the graph and in the labels. But how can I get the wind direction from my openweather API?

This seems promising but I cant access the data

```
pointRotation: function(ctx) {
    // compute angle based on whatever is your use case:
    // return ctx.dataset.data[ctx.dataIndex].a; // or .angle, or .rotation, or ...
    // return ctx.dataset.data[ctx.dataIndex].x > 42 ? 90 : -90;
    // return ctx.dataIndex % 4 ? 45 : 0;
}
```

[My weather JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/paubel/v1k9xcpj/9/).